# smoothness test

Tags: algorithms, arithmetic

An integer is $k$-smooth if its prime factors are at most $k$.
In the case where $k$ is not tiny (say $10^8 < k < 10^{10}$),
are there algorithms to test for $k$-smoothness, other than trying every prime up to $k$?

Context:

(1) The largest component $p^a$ of an odd perfect number is known to be greater than $10^{62}$.

(2) The largest prime of an odd perfect number is known to be greater than $10^8$.

Does (1) imply something stronger or weaker than (2)?

Let $LPF(n)$ denote the largest prime factor of $n$ and let $\sigma(n)$ denote the sum of the divisors of $n$.

I am interested in the minimum of $\max(p,LPF(\sigma(p^a)))$, where $p$ is prime and $p^a > 10^{62}$. We may also assume that $a$ is even since it should not be too hard to show that on odd perfect number has a component greater than $10^{62}$ that is distinct from the special component.
Here is an inefficient PARI code.

forprime(p=3,10^9,a=2; while(p^a < 10^62, a+=2); while(p^a < 10^90, f=factorint(sigma(p^a),1); s=vecmax(f[, 1]); if(s < 10^9, print([p, a])); a+=2);)

Comment: Coding questions and requests for code are likely off-topic here, but questions about appropriate algorithms are suitable here.  What research have you done?  Can you summarize what you've found so far, what algorithms you've considered, and what the best you've found so far is?

Answer (score 1):

The standard approach is to use a factoring algorithm designed to find small factors.  The state-of-the-art algorithm for that is [elliptic curve factoring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lenstra_elliptic-curve_factorization) (ECM).  Its running time is a function of the size of the smallest factor, so it is particularly useful when trying to find small factors.  I expect you should be able to find all 10-digit factors efficiently using the ECM algorithm.

Trial division is another option, and is very simple to implement.  [Pollard's p-1 factoring algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pollard%27s_p_%E2%88%92_1_algorithm) is better than trial division at finding small, but ECM is even better still.